# Crear loop a partir de coordenadas x, y dinamicas

Tags: javascript, nodejs, regex, rxjs

tengo el siguiente json que contiene un historial laboral, cada seccion inicia con el nombre de la empresa y finaliza con el ultimo movimiento de cambio de salario,

```
{
    "meta": {
    "info": {
        "PDFFormatVersion": "1.4",
            "Language": null,
            "EncryptFilterName": null,
            "IsLinearized": false,
            "IsAcroFormPresent": false,
            "IsXFAPresent": false,
            "IsCollectionPresent": false,
            "IsSignaturesPresent": false,
            "Creator": "JasperReports (reporteSemanasCotizadas)",
            "Producer": "iText 2.1.7 by 1T3XT",
            "ModDate": "D:20220713094658-05'00'",
            "CreationDate": "D:20220713094658-05'00'"
    },
    "metadata": null
},
    "pages": [
    {
        "pageInfo": {
            "num": 1,
            "scale": 1,
            "rotation": 0,
            "offsetX": 0,
            "offsetY": 0,
            "width": 612,
            "height": 792
        },
        "links": [],
        "content": [
            {
                "x": 225.13,
                "y": 108.78999999999996,
                "str": "Instituto Mexicano del Seguro Social",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 161.7399999999999,
                "height": 10,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 438.82,
                "y": 210.27999999999997,
                "str": "DD",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 8.664,
                "height": 6,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 460.82800000000003,
                "y": 210.27999999999997,
                "str": "MM",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 9.996,
                "height": 6,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 484.16800000000006,
                "y": 210.27999999999997,
                "str": "YYYY",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 16.008,
                "height": 6,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 247.53,
                "y": 282.04,
                "str": "Tu detalle de semanas cotizadas",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 116.94399999999999,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 201.57,
                "y": 141.78999999999996,
                "str": "Constancia de Semanas Cotizadas en el IMSS",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 207.8699999999999,
                "height": 10,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 462.83,
                "y": 245.03999999999996,
                "str": "363",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 13.344000000000001,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 47,
                "y": 226.03999999999996,
                "str": "NSS:",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 18.672,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 47,
                "y": 205.03999999999996,
                "str": "HERNANDEZ HIGUERA CARLOS ABDIEL",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 154.24800000000002,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 70,
                "y": 226.03999999999996,
                "str": "21139682674",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 48.928000000000004,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 75,
                "y": 246.03999999999996,
                "str": "HEHC960204HSLRGR09",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 91.584,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 47,
                "y": 246.03999999999996,
                "str": "CURP:",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 24.888,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 431.87,
                "y": 302.04,
                "str": "Semanas Reintegradas",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 83.59200000000001,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 522.1339999999999,
                "y": 302.04,
                "str": "(+)",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 10,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 264.65,
                "y": 297.44,
                "str": "Semanas Descontadas",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 82.70400000000001,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 247.32,
                "y": 306.63,
                "str": "(por disposición de recursos)",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 102.69599999999998,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 356.6879999999997,
                "y": 306.63,
                "str": "(-)",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 7.992000000000001,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 123.33,
                "y": 322.04,
                "str": "363",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 13.344000000000001,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 303.78,
                "y": 322.04,
                "str": "0",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 4.448,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 479.78,
                "y": 322.04,
                "str": "0",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 4.448,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 84.2,
                "y": 302.04,
                "str": "Semanas cotizadas IMSS",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 91.592,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 47,
                "y": 186.03999999999996,
                "str": "Estimado(a),",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 45.34400000000001,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 419.7,
                "y": 225.03999999999996,
                "str": "Total de semanas cotizadas",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 99.6,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 417.7,
                "y": 186.03999999999996,
                "str": "Fecha de emisión del reporte",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 103.60000000000002,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 436.14,
                "y": 200.60000000000002,
                "str": "13",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 8.896,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 451.7079999999999,
                "y": 200.60000000000002,
                "str": "/",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 2.224,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 460.60399999999987,
                "y": 200.60000000000002,
                "str": "07",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 8.896,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 476.1719999999998,
                "y": 200.60000000000002,
                "str": "/",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 2.224,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 485.06799999999976,
                "y": 200.60000000000002,
                "str": "2022",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 17.792,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 274.21,
                "y": 360.04,
                "str": "Tu historia laboral",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 63.57599999999999,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 312,
                "y": 453.95,
                "str": "Vigente",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 27.128000000000004,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 147,
                "y": 433.95,
                "str": "BAJA CALIFORNIA",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 70.23999999999998,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 388,
                "y": 453.95,
                "str": "Salario Base de Cotización */",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 103.59999999999998,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 44,
                "y": 453.95,
                "str": "Fecha de alta",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 48.472000000000016,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 232,
                "y": 453.95,
                "str": "Fecha de baja",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 50.695999999999984,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 147,
                "y": 453.95,
                "str": "27/09/2021",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 40.032000000000004,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 44,
                "y": 433.95,
                "str": "Entidad federativa",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 64.48,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 518.86,
                "y": 453.95,
                "str": "$ 940.68",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 31.13600000000005,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 44,
                "y": 393.95,
                "str": "Nombre del patrón",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 66.24800000000002,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 147,
                "y": 393.95,
                "str": "BAJA TRIMS",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 47.11999999999999,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 44,
                "y": 413.95,
                "str": "Registro Patronal",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 61.80000000000001,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 147,
                "y": 413.95,
                "str": "A086589310",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 45.368,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 322.26,
                "y": 489.04,
                "str": "Fecha de movimiento",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 76.47199999999998,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 129.6,
                "y": 489.04,
                "str": "Tipo de movimiento",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 69.79999999999998,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 479.32,
                "y": 489.04,
                "str": "Salario Base",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 45.352,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 340.48,
                "y": 509.04,
                "str": "01/07/2022",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 40.032000000000004,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 109.82,
                "y": 509.04,
                "str": "MODIFICACION DE SALARIO",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 109.35199999999998,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 486.43,
                "y": 509.04,
                "str": "$ 940.68",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 31.135999999999992,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 340.48,
                "y": 529.04,
                "str": "01/05/2022",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 40.032000000000004,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 109.82,
                "y": 529.04,
                "str": "MODIFICACION DE SALARIO",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 109.35199999999998,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 484.21,
                "y": 529.04,
                "str": "$ 1004.97",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 35.58399999999999,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 340.48,
                "y": 549.04,
                "str": "01/03/2022",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 40.032000000000004,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 109.82,
                "y": 549.04,
                "str": "MODIFICACION DE SALARIO",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 109.35199999999998,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 486.43,
                "y": 549.04,
                "str": "$ 940.68",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 31.135999999999992,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 340.48,
                "y": 569.04,
                "str": "01/01/2022",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 40.032000000000004,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 109.82,
                "y": 569.04,
                "str": "MODIFICACION DE SALARIO",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 109.35199999999998,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 484.21,
                "y": 569.04,
                "str": "$ 1085.32",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 35.58399999999999,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 340.48,
                "y": 589.04,
                "str": "01/11/2021",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 40.032000000000004,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 109.82,
                "y": 589.04,
                "str": "MODIFICACION DE SALARIO",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 109.35199999999998,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 484.21,
                "y": 589.04,
                "str": "$ 1074.61",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 35.58399999999999,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 340.48,
                "y": 609.04,
                "str": "27/09/2021",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 40.032000000000004,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 140.5,
                "y": 609.04,
                "str": "REINGRESO",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 48.007999999999996,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 486.43,
                "y": 609.04,
                "str": "$ 940.68",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 31.135999999999992,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 42,
                "y": 629.04,
                "str": "/* Valor del último salario base de cotización diario en pesos.",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 215.64800000000008,
                "height": 8,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 458,
                "y": 702.73,
                "str": "Paseo de la Reforma 476, P.B.",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 82.71000000000002,
                "height": 6,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 458,
                "y": 709.63,
                "str": "Col. Juárez, Cuauhtémoc",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 67.69200000000001,
                "height": 6,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 458,
                "y": 716.52,
                "str": "C.P. 06600, Ciudad de México",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 81.37199999999994,
                "height": 6,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 458,
                "y": 723.42,
                "str": "Tel. 01 800 623 23 23",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 58.37400000000002,
                "height": 6,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 458,
                "y": 730.32,
                "str": "http://atencion.contactoimss.com.mx",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 97.03800000000001,
                "height": 6,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 458,
                "y": 693.6800000000001,
                "str": "Contacto:",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 29.96,
                "height": 7,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {},
            {
                "x": 547.668,
                "y": 743.28,
                "str": "12",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 6.672,
                "height": 6,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            },
            {
                "x": 513.98,
                "y": 743.28,
                "str": "Página 1 de",
                "dir": "ltr",
                "width": 32.02200000000001,
                "height": 6,
                "fontName": "Helvetica"
            }
        ]
    }
],
    "filename": "./Employees/123.pdf"
}
```

las secciones se repiten por cada empleo que tuvo el usuario del reporte, extraje la informacion del pdf en un JSON con cordenadas x,y, lo cual me permitio obtener la informacion fija, el problema radica en las tablas de cambios de salario, ya que varian para cada usuario y las coordenadas cambian, por lo que no es posible localizarlas por medio de x,y, como puedo obtener esta informacion dinamica.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

existe manera de hacer un loop con la informacion para que de manera dinamica extraiga la informacion sin necesidad de usar las coordenadas?

encontre este codigo navegando en internet pero no puedo hacerlo funcionar en el json

```
var str="This is the number I want +2143334 !, again this is the next number I want +234343443 !, last number I want +76645 !, fininshed";
var m,results = [];
var rx = /want\s*(\+\d+)/g;
while(m=rx.exec(str)) {
    results.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(results);
```

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver la etiqueta de Java aquí?

Comment: perdon, la eliminare de la pregunta